# Unable to contact EC2 metadata service

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to fetch the instance ids of all EC2 instances in AWS using AWS SDK.

```
    AmazonEC2 ec2Service = null;
    String aWSAccessId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    String aWSSecretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    if (null != aWSAccessId && !"".equals(aWSAccessId)
            && null != aWSSecretKey && !"".equals(aWSSecretKey)) {
        ec2Service = new AmazonEC2Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(aWSAccessId, aWSSecretKey));
    }
    DescribeInstancesResult result = ec2Service.describeInstances();
    String instanceid = EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId();
    String availabilityZone = EC2MetadataUtils.getAvailabilityZone();
    System.out.println("availabilityZone-----> "+availabilityZone);
     System.out.println("instanceid-----> "+instanceid);
    List<Reservation> reservations = result.getReservations();
    System.out.println("reservations-----> "+reservations.toString());

    for (Reservation reservation : reservations) 
    {
        List<Instance> instances = reservation.getInstances();
        System.out.println("instances-----> "+instances.size());
        for (Instance instance : instances) 
        {

            System.out.println("Instances----> "+instance.getInstanceId());
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to fetch the instances.I also tried to use the EC2MetadataUtils.java to fetch the details by configuring the sdk in my eclipse ide.

```
    EC2MetadataUtils ec2Meta = new EC2MetadataUtils();
    String amiId = ec2Meta.getAmiId();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata ----amiId---> "+amiId);

    String availabilityZone = ec2Meta.getAvailabilityZone();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata ----AvailabilityZone---> "+availabilityZone);

    /*String eC2InstanceRegion = ec2Meta.getEC2InstanceRegion();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata ----eC2InstanceRegion---> "+eC2InstanceRegion);*/

    String instanceId = ec2Meta.getInstanceId();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata ----instanceId---> "+instanceId);

    InstanceInfo instanceInfo = ec2Meta.getInstanceInfo();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata  "+instanceInfo.getAccountId());
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata  "+instanceInfo.getInstanceId());
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata  "+instanceInfo.getPrivateIp());
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata "+instanceInfo.getRegion());
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata  "+instanceInfo.getArchitecture());
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata "+instanceInfo.getInstanceType());
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata  "+instanceInfo.getVersion());
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata  "+instanceInfo.getImageId());     
    String publicKey = EC2MetadataUtils.getPublicKey();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata "+publicKey);      
     IAMInfo AMInstanceProfileInfo = EC2MetadataUtils.getIAMInstanceProfileInfo();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata "+AMInstanceProfileInfo.lastUpdated);

    String MacAddress = EC2MetadataUtils.getMacAddress();
    System.out.println("Ec2 Metadata "+MacAddress);
```

But I am getting null only for the initial fields and in the end I am getting the below error.

```
Ec2 Metadata  null
Ec2 Metadata  null
Ec2 Metadata  null

Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to contact EC2 metadata service.
```

Comment: Sanity Check: Are you running this code from an EC2 instance?  The EC2 metadata service is only available from within your instance, and the service gets metadata describing the running instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: NO, I am running the code outside the EC2 instance. KIndly let me know how to access the metadata of EC2 outside of the instance. Thank you.

Comment: Focus on your first code snippet... the request that returns [DescribeInstancesResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesResult.html). You can get everything you need from the Reservation and Instance collections like you've already attempted.  Start by debugging that. Is the response from AWS SDK successful? Are any reservations or instances returning with the response? If not, why? (Perhaps because you have not specified a region for your AmazonEC2Client? The SDK request will only return instances in your requested region.)

Answer (score 1):

Anthony correctly mentioned in his comments that the EC2 metadata service is only available from within your running EC2 instance. I had a similar situation where I needed region information for all the EC2 instances associated to an AWS account. This is how I am reading region information for an instance:

```
List<Instance> ec2Instances = describeInstancesResult.getReservations().stream().map(d -> d.getInstances()).flatMap(l -> l.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
//describeInstancesResult is the response of describeInstance operation on the aws client generated for a given aws account.

ec2Instances.stream().forEach((instance) -> {
    String region = instance.getPlacement().getAvailabilityZone();
    //do operations on the region value.
}
```